# How does OpenDDS communicate with both RTI and OpenSplice

Tags: data-distribution-service

I know that OpenDDS have demonstrated inter-operability with both RTI and OpenSplice, but I do not know where I can find this sample or where I can get some help files.

Anyone can help me? it is really really important for me and I will appreciate if you can give me a reply :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interoperability has been demonstrated using the famous DDS Shapes example, you can find the OpenDDS version within the OpenDDS release. The version demonstrated last year is part of OpenDDS 3.5.

Comment: thanks a lot, that really help me a lot, I will there and download one :) best wishes